# GitHub Actions Terraform State file cant be parsed

Tags: json, bash, terraform, github-actions

I am currently using terraform to provision Infrastructure in the cloud. On Top of Terraform I run GitHub Actions to automate even more Steps.

In this case, after provisioning the infrastructure I generate an inventory file (for ansible) with a bash script using the generated cluster.tfstate to parse names and ips.

However the Script cant run, as it throws following error

```
Run bash ./generate-inventory.sh cluster.tfstate > ../hosts.ini
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9
Error: Process completed with exit code 4.
```

Running it locally however works. When i do a cat on the cluster.tfstate inside the workflow the following is the case

```
Run cat cluster.tfstate
***
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.0.1",
  "serial": 386,
  "lineage": "3d16a659-b093-551c-b3ab-a1cf8aa5031c",
  "outputs": ***
    "master_ip_addresses": ***
      "value": ***
```

Does GitHub Actions modify the json that is evaluated by my script because of Secrets i have created? Or are the stars only in the output in the shell?

The Code of the workflow can be seen here https://github.com/eco-bench/eco-bench/blob/main/.github/workflows/terraform.yml

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if it's your script or the input which causes the error? Try running only the script with a dummy JSON hardcoded input, try validating the JSON input from the script or validating it first, to see if it is valid JSON. Would that give more information about the problem?

Comment: Use the `local_file` provider to generate the Ansible inventory instead. It would be much easier and probably also fix the issue here.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, managed to solve this issue by using `local_file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following did the trick

```
source "local_file" "AnsibleInventory" {

  content = templatefile("inventory.tmpl",
    {
      worker = {
      for key, instance in google_compute_instance.worker :
      instance.name => instance.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
      }
      master = {
      for key, instance in google_compute_instance.master :
      instance.name => instance.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
      }
    }
  )
  filename = "./inventory.ini"
}
```

The Template looks like this

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=lucas

[cloud]
%{ for ip in master ~}
${name} ${ip}
%{ endfor ~}

[edge]
%{ for ip in worker ~}
${ip}
%{ endfor ~}

[cloud:vars]
kubernetes_role=master

[edge:vars]
kubernetes_role=edge
```